# i want to calculate what emotions are impacting sentiments how can i do this in R?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

[emotiofile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtgeG.png)I have 10 columns, with 8 emotion scores and 2 sentiments scores
emotions like anger sad happy...
sentiments being positive and negative
each emotion and sentiments have scores again ranging from 0 to x
how can i calculate which emotion combinations are impacting positive sentiment or negative by using R language ?

Comment: Could you publish some usable data to copy and paste in R? It will help to help you. You can do `dput(your_data)` and paste here the output. If you would not use your data, you can put some fake data equal to yours, to copy and paste.

Comment: hi thanks, i uploaded the excel file image can you please check

Comment: Generally is not very useful adding an image of your data. You could import them in R with `read_excel()` of `readxl` package if it's a .xls or .xlsx, or you can use `read.csv()` for .csv, then `dput(data)` and paste the output. After, I think you can focus more what does it mean your data, and what you want, because imho it's not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very vague and does not have any specific code to further understand what you mean (reproducible example). It seems to me that you need to understand the data using descriptive statistics first. Functions such as `summary`, `head`, `names`, `levels`, `sapply` and `nlevels` (by column) can help you to begin understanding what you're working with.

I've found this article that can help you start understanding: https://machinelearningmastery.com/descriptive-statistics-examples-with-r/

Once you have an idea of what your data looks like, try looking into this article to see the different types of analysis that exist and which fit best for your situation. Text mining is not a simple task but there are many techniques that can help you find your answers:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/sentiment-analysis-R

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I think that using `summary()` for the data in the image could be misleading, having not continuous variables only.

Comment: That's why I mention "start", it's hard to determine kapardhi is looking for. I've added more functions that can help visualize the data.